# XSLT with not nestable tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt, multiple-columns

I have an XML document which contains both structure (section) tags and display tags (columns):

```
<document>
  <new-column/>
  <section1>
    text
  </section1>
  <section2>
    text
    <new-column/>
    text
  </section2>
</document>
```

I am writing an XSLT to display this as HTML, and the logical way would be to use a `<div>` tag to display the text in separate columns, so I'd have to convert `<new-column>` into `<div>`.
However, the `<div>` requires a closing `</div>` tag, with all the comprising elements in between, but then the document would not be well-formed, with `<section>` and `<new-column>` being wrongly nested.
One solution would be to add closing `</section>` tags like this:

```
<document>
  <new-column>
    <section1>
      text
    </section1>
    <section2>
      text
    </section2>
  </new-column>
  <new-column>
    <section2>
      text
    </section2>
  </new-column>
</document>
```

However, I was wondering if anyone has a better idea, such as adding text to a div section on the fly, or perhaps using a different solution for multiple column (and multiple pages) display.
TIA

Comment: change <new-column/> to </new-column> in required text to make XML well formation.

Comment: The output of XSLT will automatically be well-formed, unless you are hand-constructing tags (which is an EXTREMELY bad practice). What have you tried, what are you getting, what do you want to get instead? (Remember, that HTML conceptually *does* have end-tags for everything; it's just that the HTML parser will automatically insert them at appropriate points if they're missing. Things must be properly nested for the document to be a tree, and the document is always a tree.)

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing, and you are right: it's horribly dangerous. The only way I can think of to convert the new-column tags into a div tag is to convert the empty new-column tag into an opening tag, and adding a corresponding closing new-column tag right before the next new-column tag. BTW, thanks to Rudramuni for spotting the typo, I meant to say in the second listing </ new-column> instead of <new-column />

Comment: Implementation issues aside, what is the ideal HTML output you would like to see in the end?

Comment: Good question. I guess I want something like this: <document>
  <div>
    <span id="section1">
      text
    </span>
    <span id="section2">
      text
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span id="section2">
      text
    </span>
  </div>
</document>

Comment: If you're constructing string output, it's your responsibility to write the stylesheet to do it properly. One strong piece of advice: Life will be much, much simpler if you ensure that the output of every template is well-formed; then, by recursion/implication, it all stays well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="text-by-col" match="text()" use="generate-id(preceding::new-column[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
       <xsl:for-each select=".//new-column">
            <div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('text-by-col', generate-id())" mode="span"/>
            </div>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="span">
    <span id="{local-name(parent::*)}"><xsl:copy/></span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am still trying to adapt your solution (obviously, my post was a very simplified version of the real thing), but yes, it seems like this is what I was looking for. THANKS A LOT!